# Pressure-Velocity relation at a point in a flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, aerodynamics

How can we relate pressure and velocity at the same point in a fluid flow?

Why does pressure decrease with increase in velocity?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle

Answer (score 2):

The total energy doesn't change, only the fraction that is potential energy (equivalent to pressure) and the fraction that is kinetic energy (equivalent to speed squared). So each particle will be somewhere on a continuum between only potential energy (at the stagnation point) and only kinetic energy (at high speed at a point of vanishing pressure). The sum of both kinds of energy will be constant if no external energy sources distort the picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, [*as explained clearly here*](http://cloud.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-bernoulli).

The way a parcel of fluid accelerates from one velocity to another is by falling through a pressure difference.